# Is is safe for deferred .done() to use a variable from outer scope

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred, deferred

In the following code, will `myVar` always be available to the done function? If my `deferreds` take a long time to finish working and the code has moved on, will it know about `myVar`?

```
function doWork() {
    var deferreds = [deferredObject1, deferredObject2];

    var myVar = "Derp";    

    jQuery.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(() => {
       doStuffToMyVar(myVar);
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, but if you change the value of `myVar`, the value will be changed in the `done` callback.

Comment: `myvar` is global, so it'd be available regardless. what you should be asking is what value it's going to have. it could either be the value that was in effect when you did the deferment, or it could be the "real" value when the deferred call actually fires. since those are at two different times, you could be dealing with two different values.

Comment: @MarcB we don't have enough context in the question to declare myVar as a "global". If the lines above and below the excerpt posted are a function scope, then the best we can say is that yes, the cope will still exist when the callback fires.

Comment: @MarcB The code would be in a function, not global. I updated my example.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Why post an answer as a comment?

Comment: @JoeFrambach laziness since my *answer* isn't complete. I'm also pretty sure there is someone or something somewhere that will explain it more in detail. Much more than what I'm willing to write right now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always OK to use variables in a higher scope and `.done()` handlers are no different in that regard.  So, it's perfectly fine to use `myVar` inside the `.done()` handler.

What you do have to watch for is the timing of when variables change.  As I presume you know, the `.done()` handler will get called some time in the future and it's exact timing is likely unknown (assuming asynchronous operations are being used).  As such, if there is any other code that can modify `myVar`, you have to make very sure that you know how that modification might interact with the timing of the `.done()` handler.

In an extreme example to illustrate the point, this would cause you problems:

```
function doWork() {
    var deferreds = [deferredObject1, deferredObject2];

    var myVar = "Derp";    

    jQuery.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(() => {
       doStuffToMyVar(myVar);
    });
    myVar = null;
}
```

because `myVar` would be set to `null` before the `.done()` handler was called and thus you'd end up with `doStuffToMyVar(null)` which isn't what you want.

There are obviously much more subtle examples where other parts of your function or other methods that run before the `.done()` handler actually gets called might change data out from underneath you.  This doesn't mean that there's any rule not to use variables from a higher scope, just that you should be aware of these types of issues and if it might be an issue in your code, then you can protect against it by either making a copy of the variable in question, creating a new closure to pass the variable into, etc...